# Neural network: Batch-version affine layer back-propagation weight matrix updation

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I'm trying to follow a book about deep learning but I found some part about affine layer of the network confusing. Say I have a network which accepts some handwriting number(`0 ~ 9`) images(mnist), which are flatten into one dimensional array, e.g. `np.array([123, 255, 0, ...])` and it will output the scores for each possible output, e.g. `np.array([0., 0., 0.3, 0., 0., 0.6, 0., 0., 0., 0.1])`(So the image may be the number `5`).

Here is my implementation of affine layer:

```
class AffineLayer(object):
    ...
    def backward(self, dy):
        dx = np.dot(dy, self._W.T)
        self._dW = np.dot(self._x.T, dy) # Question related part
        self._db = np.sum(dy, axis=0)
        dx = dx.reshape(self._original_x_shape)
        return dx
    ...
```

Here is some explanations:

- `self._W` is the weight matrix.
- The part of concern here is `self._dW = np.dot(self._x.T, y) # Question related part`.
- This line is derived from an equality:

  `X               *            W     +    B    =    Y`     
  `(N,2)     matrix product    (2,3)      (1,3)      (N,3).`
- The notation `(2,)` comes from the `X.shape` of `numpy.array`, etc. To simplify my problem I choose these dimension numbers.

End of terminology, now here comes the question:

> By some math(omitted), we can arrive the equality used in back-propagation,( so `self._dW = np.dot(self._x.T, y)` is used in the code):
>
> `d L         T         d L`   
>   `---   ==   X     *    ---`   
>   `d W                   d Y`   
>                               
>   `(2,3)    (2,N)   *    (N,3).`
>
> Notice that no matter how I adjust `N`, which is the size of the batch, the dimension of `dL/dW`, the partial-derivative-of-L weight-matrix, won't change, and it's always `(2,3)`.
>
> Does this mean that the total effect of these `N` batches are combined/condensed into the `dL/dW`? This is related to how I would implement the output layer, e.g. softmax-cross-entropy layer as the final layer. My current conclusion for this is that `N` batch means doing the back-propagation `N` times and the division of the gradient `dL/dW` by `N` is needed to average/amortize the total effect of that batch. But now it seems like I only have to do it one time and the division should be "in the first step".

### Edit:

I also find the version which seems to divide it at last step [mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning - GitHub](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/d15df08a69ed33ae16a2fff874f83b57a956172c/src/network2.py#L285), for reference.

Since the softmax-cross-entropy layer class is the last layer of the net, in back-propagation it will becomes the "first step" as I mentioned above:

```
class SoftmaxCrossEntropy(object):
    ...
    def backward(self, dout=1):
        batch_size = self._t.shape[0]
        # one-hot
        if self._t.size == self._y.size:
            dx = (self._y - self._t) / batch_size # <-- why divided by N here?
        else: # not one-hot
            dx = self._y * 1
            dx[np.arange(batch_size), self._t] -= 1
            dx = dx / batch_size       #    <-- why divided by N here?
        return dx
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Does it means that the effect of these N batches of input are combined/condensed into the dW?*

Since the i-th row of `X` is a 1-d array that is related to the i-th flatten image. If I transpose `X` into

`T`    
    `X    ,` then it's columns to represent those flatten images. If `N` increase, although

the dimension of the result(`dW`) won't change, the intermediate steps of computing each element of

`T        d L`     
 `dW   =   X    *    ---`     
                    `d Y    ,` increase, which means

`N`                                                      
 `dW     =    Sum  (  pixel_info     *   class_scores_deriv.       )`  
   `i,j       n=1               i,n                         n,j      ,` which `N` is the batch

size. Clearly each `class_scores_derivative_(n,j)` "join" the determination of `dW_(i,j)`, but this implies that the division by `batch_size = N` is needed, because the summation above is not the average effect of that batch, but what I need is `dW` to represent the **average** impact of that batch. If I divide each element of `class_scores_deriv.`, which is the line
`dx = (self._y - self._t) / batch_size`, then

`N                         1`                             
   `Sum  (  pixel_info     *  ---  class_scores_deriv.    )`  
   `n=1               i,n      N                   n,j`       
        `1    N`                                                      
    `=  ---  Sum  (  pixel_info     *   class_scores_deriv.       )`  
        `N   n=1               i,n                         n,j`       
        `1`        
    `=  --- dW`    
        `N       ,` which is the real `dW` I want.

So the answer (I hope) should be

> The entire batch determine the dW, but to condense it, the divisions in `SoftmaxCrossEntropy::backward(self, dout=1)` is needed.